# iOS Deprecation Ramifications

Tags: ios, deprecated

I just came to realize that my project is currently using methods that are "discouraged" in iOS 4.0+. I fear that deprecation is soon inevitable. However, in practical terms, I'm not sure what this would mean for my project. Does it mean that users who attempt to run the app on a future iOS version will experience runtime errors or does it simply mean that I'll have compile-time errors when maintaining it on future iOS SDK's? Or, am I missing the boat (and the river) entirely?

Thanks

Comment: Specifically, I'm using UIView beginAnimations:context: all throughout and am not looking forward to converting them all to block format. So I figured now would be as good a time to ask as ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that they'll remove the old method entirely, [Apple just suggests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) (see "Animations") that you use the newer format.

As stated, if you want your projects to support iOS versions <4.0, continue using the old format. If not, it's recommended to update, but if you choose not to, don't be too worried about it. (at least not until the old format becomes officially deprecated)

EDIT: Just re-read the question, and to answer that specifically; no, not you nor any other users would experience errors in the future (provided you're using the functions correctly) - even if it *does* become deprecated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why users would experience no errors? I'm trying to understand the practical implications and limitations of deprecation.

Comment: As far as I know, the feature will remain in iOS for some time (possibly indefinitely), and technically _should_ work as it did originally. Generally things are deprecated because better, more efficient methods are available which are then recommended, not because the older methods won't work. (and so along with this, because the older methods _do_ still work, they often aren't removed, simply 'deprecated')

Comment: Again, specifically from Apple; "A method identified as deprecated has been superseded and may become unsupported in the future." - In some cases do note that deprecated methods are actually _unsafe_, but I don't believe that's the case with the animation format.